# storageKey option not working for server side rendered mui-datatable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, local-storage, mui-datatable

I am working with `mui-datatable`. And I have a few columns visible by default and a few of them are hidden. When a user changes the selected columns from the update columns filter. I want to persist the selected columns when the user comes back.

There was a `storageKey` property in the `mui-datatable` options to persist the data in local storage that I was trying. But it doesn't seem to work. Does this property doesn't work with server-side rendering?

Is there any other way to persist and use this data in `mui-datatable`